# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEachNodeAfterFilter')

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I'm trying to utilize the AG Grid API in order to select all rows, after having applied a filter. I'm logging the `api` object successfully and the `forEachNodeAfterFilter()` exists in it's prototype, however, React throws `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEachNodeAfterFilter')`

```
const ProductSelectionHeader = (props: IProductSelectionHeaderProps) => {
    const { api } = props;
    if (!api) return;
    //returns the gridApi object and forEachNodeAfterFilter() exists in its prototype
    console.log(api)     

    return (
        <MenuItem value="1" onClick={() => api.forEachNodeAfterFilter(node => node.setSelected(true))}>
            Select All
        </MenuItem>
    )
})

const columnDefs = [
    {
        field: 'checkbox',
        headerName: '',
        checkboxSelection: true,
        headerComponent: ProductSelectionHeader,
        headerComponentParams: {
            allItemIds
        },
        suppressMenu: true,
    },
]
```

[image]

Comment: can you share how are you calling your component? I mean what props are you passing to it

Answer (score 0):

Try to create your onClick function first.

```js
const ProductSelectionHeader = (props: IProductSelectionHeaderProps) => {
    const { api } = props;
    const onClick = () => api.forEachNodeAfterFilter(node => node.setSelected(true))

    return (
        <MenuItem value="1" onClick={onClick}>
            Select All
        </MenuItem>
    )
}
```

And you don't need to check if `api` is there.

UPD:
There is also a method `api.selectAllFiltered()`.